# Airflow dag bash task lag on remote executions

Tags: python, scheduling, directed-acyclic-graphs, airflow

I am experimenting with Airflow to replace our existing cron orchestration and everything looks promising.   I have successfully installed and gotten a dag to be scheduled and executed, but I noticed that their is a significant delay between each of the tasks I have specified (at least 15 minutes to 60 minutes).

My dag is defined as follows

Am I missing something to make them run one right after the other?

I am not using celery 
both scheduler and webserver are running on the same host
and yes - need to call for a remote execution (working on some form of local until then)
and no cannot install airflow on the remote server
Dag should run once a day at 1 am UTC, follow the set path of tasks I have given it.

> ```
> import airflow
> from builtins import range
> from airflow import DAG
> from airflow.operators.bash_operator import BashOperator
> from airflow.models import DAG
> from datetime import datetime, timedelta
>
> args = {
>     'owner': 'user1',
>     'depends_on_past': False,
>     'start_date': airflow.utils.dates.days_ago(2),
>     'email': ['data-etl-errors@user1.com'],
>     'email_on_failure': True,
>     'email_on_retry': False,
>     'wait_for_downstream': True,
>     'schedule_interval': None,
>     'depends_on_past': True,
>     'retries': 1,
>     'retry_delay': timedelta(minutes=5)
> }
>
>  dag = DAG(
>        dag_id='airflow_pt1'
>      , default_args=args
>      , schedule_interval='0 1 * * *'
>      , dagrun_timeout=timedelta(hours=8))
>
>  task1 = BashOperator(
>        task_id='task1'
>      , bash_command='ssh user1@remoteserver /path/to/remote/execution/script_task1.sh'
>      , dag=dag,env=None, output_encoding='utf-8')
>
>  task2 = BashOperator(
>        task_id='task2'
>      , bash_command='ssh user1@remoteserver /path/to/remote/execution/script_task2.sh'
>      , dag=dag,env=None, output_encoding='utf-8')
>
>  task3 = BashOperator(
>        task_id='task3'
>      , bash_command='ssh user1@remoteserver /path/to/remote/execution/script_task3.sh'
>      , dag=dag,env=None, output_encoding='utf-8')
>
>  task4 = BashOperator(
>        task_id='task4'
>      , bash_command='ssh user1@remoteserver /path/to/remote/execution/script_task4.sh'
>      , dag=dag,env=None, output_encoding='utf-8')
>
>  task2.set_upstream(task1)
>  task3.set_upstream(task1)
>  task4.set_upstream(task2)
> ```

Note I have not executed airflow backfill (is that important?)

Comment: I'm not sure the `directed-acyclic-graphs` tag is appropriate here -- subject-matter expertise in graph theory wouldn't help someone answer this question, so someone following that tag in their feed is likely to find this question not of interest to them unless they're *also* following `airflow`.

Comment: BTW, are you sure the tasks are actually exiting when you expect them to be complete? Have you checked the process table?

Comment: I have and the captured logs/stdout on the task monitor shows up nicely.   I curious if I require multiple workers for the scheduler to queue up subsequent tasks

Comment: It's good that stdout appears complete, but again, have you verified that the process actually exited? SSH processes can sometimes hang at the end of operation if, for instance, any child processes they leave behind are holding open file descriptors that were on the connection's stdin/stdout/stderr.

Answer (score 1):

Found the issue
I had not altered the configuration from sequential to localExecutor in airflow.cfg file

I found my answer through https://stlong0521.github.io/20161023%20-%20Airflow.html

and watching the detailed video in https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Pr0FrvIIfTU